# How to detect a specific build of webkit in a client browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, webkit

Because of WebSocket protocol changes in WebKit nightly build r59903, I need to know whether I should run additional scripts. That depends on WebKit build number. I'm using jQuery as a platform, so assume `$.browser.webkit` is `true`. Then how do I check whether client WebKit build is 59903 or higher? `$.browser.version` tells something like `533.17.8`, or `533` etc and not build number.

**EDIT** The problem is that I need to decide whether to run additional stuff preferably at a page load stage (actually, there are two possible scenarios I should choose of). However, I can detect WebSocket protocol changes after a page was loaded (server simply refuses a connection with an unsupported protocol version, and WebSocket object silently closes).

Comment: Can't you just target the version of the browser to which the webkit build was applied?

Comment: Perhaps you can detect the changes to the WebSocket implementation instead of the build number?

Comment: @Marko Ivanovski It's less reliable, I think. Suppose, a user uses some not well-known WebKit browser.
@Gert G I've added some comment to the question why it's not preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build number is a completely arbitrary value, it may jump ahead, change format, and is never part of a release version of WebKit.

Can you not test for the functionality you need or use try/catch and fall back to your "additional scripts" stuff?

Comment: I've added comment to the question regarding your idea. However, I consider such a solution as the only solution I know.